# How to fix this block matrix so that it can have same spacing between its columns

Tags: formatting, matrices, arrows, columns

```
\begin{document}

\[
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
& & & & -1 & -1 & \dots & \dots & -1
\\
&&& & 0 & 0 & \dots & \dots & 0
\\
&  \text{\huge{$\Gamma(\mathbb{Z}_n)+nI$}} &&& \ldots&\ldots & \dotso & \dotso &\dots  
\\
&&& & \ldots&\ldots & \dotso & \dotso &\dots  
\\
& & & &   0 & 0 & \dots & \dots & 0
\\
-1&0  \dotso & \dots & 0& & & & 
\\
-1 &0  \dots & \dots & 0& & & & 
\\
\dotso &\dotso  & \dotso &   \dotso & & &\text{\huge{$I$}}
\\          
\dotso &\dotso  & \dotso & \dotso & & 
\\
-1 &0 & \dotso & 0& & & & 
\end{array}
\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

The output I am getting is [image]

There is a lot of gap coming between the 1st and the 2nd column in the left block.
There is a lot of gap between $-1$ and $0$ in the lower end of the left side of the matrix.

It can be seen that the matrix is not formatted properly.
Is there any way I can fix this?

I will be grateful if someone can fix this for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pNiceArray}{w{c}{1em}w{c}{1em}w{c}{1em}w{c}{1em}w{c}{1em}w{c}{1em}w{c}{1em}w{c}{1em}w{c}{1em}}
\Block{5-4}<\Large>{~\Gamma(\mathbb{Z}_n)+nI}& & & & -1 & -1 & \Cdots & \Cdots &  -1
\\
&&& & 0 & 0 & \Cdots & \Cdots &  0
\\
&  
&&& \Vdots&\Vdots & \Ddots & & \Vdots\\
& &&& \Vdots&\Vdots & &\Ddots  & \Vdots\\
& & & &   0 & 0 & \Cdots & \Cdots & 0
\\
-1&0  & \Cdots & \Cdots & 0& \Block{5-4}<\Large>{I}& &  
\\
-1 &0 & \Cdots & \Cdots & 0& & & 
\\
\Vdots&\Vdots   & \Ddots &   & \Vdots& &
\\          
\Vdots&\Vdots   & & \Ddots & \Vdots & 
\\
-1 &0 & \Cdots & \Cdots&0 & & & 
\end{pNiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: Per request no package beyond `amsfonts` which you seem to be loading.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}

\[
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
& & && & -1 & -1 & \dots & \dots & -1
\\
&&& && 0 & 0 & \dots & \dots & 0
\\
& & \text{\makebox[0pt]{\large{$\Gamma(\mathbb{Z}_n)+nI$}}} &&& \ldots&\ldots & \dotso & \dotso &\dots  
\\
&&& & & \ldots&\ldots & \dotso & \dotso &\dots  
\\
& & & &&   0 & 0 & \dots & \dots & 0
\\
-1&0 & \dotso & \dots & 0& & & & 
\\
-1 &0 & \dots & \dots & 0& & & & 
\\
\dotso &\dotso  & \dotso &   \dotso & & & & \text{\makebox[0pt]{\large\huge{$I$}}}
\\          
\dotso &\dotso  & \dotso & \dotso & & 
\\
-1 &0 & \dotso & 0& 0 & & & 
\end{array}
\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}

\[
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc@{}ccccc@{}cc}
& & && & -1 & -1 & \cdots & \cdots & -1
\\
&&& && 0 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0
\\
& & \text{\makebox[0pt]{\large{$\Gamma(\mathbb{Z}_n)+nI$}}} &&& \vdots&\vdots 
& \ddots\,\, &  &\vdots  
\\[-1ex]
&&& & & \vdots&\vdots &  & \,\,\ddots &\vdots  
\\
& & & &&   0 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0
\\
-1&0 & \dotso & \dots & 0& & & & 
\\
-1 &0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0& & & & 
\\
\vdots &\vdots  & \ddots\,\, &    & \vdots & & & \text{\makebox[0pt]{\large\huge{$I$}}}
\\[-1ex]          
\vdots &\vdots  & & \,\,\ddots & \vdots & & 
\\
-1 &0 & \cdots & \cdots& 0 & & & 
\end{array}
\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot but do you know how to do these things without any package such as 'nicematrix" ,

Comment: @Math_Freak If you post an MWE which indicates which packages you are using, and specify which you do not like, one can do that. Otherwise it is hard. I do not know if "package such as `nicematrix`" also includes `amsmath`, obviously you are loading `amsfonts` but how would one know which packages you do not use if you do not post a complete example?

Comment: I understand your point. thanks a lot Sir, one more question , can you just specify what I was doing wrong in my question and what did you do specifically to fix that

Comment: What is the use of \mbox ? I was just trying to understand the use of each command in Latex and thats why asking you, I hope I am not disturbing , I am just learning LaTeX , so I am not so efficient , sorry for asking questions

Comment: @Math_Freak `\mbox` is mostly obsolete, use `\text`. You should write a code in the question which starts with `\documentclass` and loads all necessary packages, and should be compilable. And if you decide for yourself that you only want to use very basic packages, that's perfectly fine, but please add this information to the question.

Comment: If I type \text , I get the same old thing which I was having problem with, only when I use \makebox[0pt] which you used I am getting the correct output,

Comment: I was just wondering if you could just explain the use of \makebox[0pt] which you have used

Comment: @Math_Freak You wrote `\mbox`. which is indeed more or less out of use. `\makebox[0pt]` creates a box of width `0pt`, which means that the column do not get wider. While in most modern approaches one would not need `\makebox` at the user level, but rather use something like `\mathclap` from `mathtools` instead (which I didn't use because you said no packages), it underlies many macros that are on the market.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir for explaining

Answer (score 1):

Use 1) `\hidewidth large text\hidewidth`, 2) `\quad` after `\left(`, 3) `\phantom+` before some zeros:

```
$$
\left(\quad   \def\+{\phantom+}
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
& & & & -1 & -1 & \dots & \dots & -1
\\
&&& & \+0 & \+0 & \dots & \dots & \+0
\\
&  \hidewidth\text{\huge{$\Gamma(\mathbb{Z}_n)+nI$}}\hidewidth &&& \ldots&\ldots & \dotso & \dotso &\dots  
\\
&&& & \ldots&\ldots & \dotso & \dotso &\dots  
\\
& & & &   \+0 & \+0 & \dots & \dots & \+0
\\
-1&0  \dotso & \dots & 0& & & & 
\\
-1 &0  \dots & \dots & 0& & & & 
\\
\dotso &\dotso  & \dotso &   \dotso & & &\text{\huge{$I$}}
\\          
\dotso &\dotso  & \dotso & \dotso & & 
\\
-1 &0 & \dotso & 0& & & & 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir.Can you please explain what you did which fixed the work? I just wanted to know how to fix these things on my own so that I dont have to post such questions here again?

Comment: I explained it. Se my answer 1), 2), 3). The 1) is main idea of solving this problem: `\hidewidth` is negative space which allows to protrude the text over the column boundaries.

Comment: Yes , but I dont understand the use of \phantom, \quad

Comment: I am new to LaTeX, so sorry for asking questions, hope you dont mind

Comment: `\quad` inserts a space equal to font size. You can try to remove it and you can see what happens: the `\hidewidth` causes that the text laps to the left bracket. And `\phantom` creates a space equal to the size of the text. You can remove the `\+` and you can see what happens: -1 above 0 are centered, but it does not look so pretty.