# Displaying matrix with dots

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I want to display the following matrix (ignore the red box):
[image]
But all I can come up with is the following, which is not what I want beacuse of the diagonal and vertical dots:
[image]

I want the vertical dots to be more "centered" with no gap between the two segments, and the diagonal dots to be on the same line.
Here's the code for the matrix:

```
\begin{pmatrix}
    2\al - 4u_{1}^{2} & -4u_{1}u_{2} & \cdots & -4u_{1}u_{n} & -4u_{1}(v+1)\\
    -4u_{1}u_{2} & 2\al - 4u_{2}^{2} & \cdots & -4u_{2}u_{n} & -4u_{2}(v+1)\\
    \vdots & \ddots &  & \vdots & \vdots\\
    \vdots &  & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
     -4u_{1}u_{n-1} & \cdots & 2\al -4u_{n-1}^{2} & -4u_{n-1}u_{n} & -4u_{n-1}(v+1)\\
    -4u_{1}u_{n} & \cdots & -4u_{n-1}u_{n} & 2\al - 4u_{n}^{2} & -4u_{n}(v+1)\\
    -4u_{1}(v+1) & \cdots & -4u_{n-1}(v+1) & -4u_{n}(v+1) & -2\al + 4(v+1)^{2}
\end{pmatrix}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You may start by adapting some existing answer e.g. [formatting - How to fix this block matrix so that it can have same spacing between its columns - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538124/how-to-fix-this-block-matrix-so-that-it-can-have-same-spacing-between-its-column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with `nicematrix`. Note that you must compile twice.

The commands `\Cdots`, `\Vdots` and `\Ddots` should replace `\cdots`, `\vdots` and `ddots` respectively. These commands will continue the dots through empty cells, so a few extra `&`s are needed. Also, instead of a row of `&`s to get the space in the middle, just use `\\[<length>]` to end the previous row. I used a length of `3ex`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\[\begin{pNiceMatrix}
    2\alpha - 4u_{1}^{2} & -4u_{1}u_{2} & \Cdots && -4u_{1}u_{n} & -4u_{1}(v+1)\\
    -4u_{1}u_{2} & 2\alpha - 4u_{2}^{2} & \Cdots && -4u_{2}u_{n} & -4u_{2}(v+1)\\
    \Vdots & & \Ddots && \Vdots & \Vdots\\[3ex]
     -4u_{1}u_{n-1} & \Cdots && 2\alpha -4u_{n-1}^{2} & -4u_{n-1}u_{n} & -4u_{n-1}(v+1)\\
    -4u_{1}u_{n} & \Cdots && -4u_{n-1}u_{n} & 2\alpha - 4u_{n}^{2} & -4u_{n}(v+1)\\
    -4u_{1}(v+1) & \Cdots && -4u_{n-1}(v+1) & -4u_{n}(v+1) & -2\alpha + 4(v+1)^{2}
\end{pNiceMatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: exactly what I wanted, thanks for your time!